# How do I copy an HTML document and edit the copy based upon the selection, without altering the original document?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, range, selection

I have an HTML document, and I would like to remove some of the tags from it dynamically using Javascript, based on whether the tags are within the current selection or not. However, I do not want to update the actual document on the page, I want to make a copy of the whole page's HTML and edit that copy. The problem is that the `Range` object I get from `selection.getRangeAt(0)` still points to the original document, as far as I can see.

I've managed to get editing the original document in place with this code:

```
var node = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;
var allWithinRangeOfParent = node.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (var i=0, el; el = allWithinRangeParent[i]; i++) {
    // The second parameter says to include the element 
    // even if it's not fully selected
    if (selection.containsNode(el, true) ) {
        el.remove();
    }
 }
```

But what I want to do is to somehow perform the same operation with removing elements, but remove them from a *copy* of the original HTML. I've made the copy like this: `var fullDocument = $('html').clone();` How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either dynamically add a class or data attribute to all your elements on load before you clone so that you have a point of reference then grab the class or data attribute on the common ancestor and remove it from the clone. I can give an example if you like? Along these lines - http://jsfiddle.net/9s9hpc2v/ isn't properly working exactly right but you get the gist.

```
$('*').each(function(i){
    $(this).attr('data-uniqueId', i);
});
var theclone = $('#foo').clone();


function laa(){
    var node = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;
    if(node.getElementsByTagName){

    var allWithinRangeOfParent =  $(node).find('*');
        console.log(allWithinRangeOfParent, $(allWithinRangeOfParent).attr('data-uniqueId'));
        $.each(allWithinRangeOfParent, function(){
            theclone.find('[data-uniqueId="'+$(this).attr('data-uniqueId')+'"]').remove();
        });
        console.log(theclone.html());
    }
}
$('button').click(laa);
```